# Toggle View Visibility

Tags: android, view, toggle, visibility

I have found lots of questions about `View` `visibility`. I already know the difference between .GONE and .`INVISIBLE`. What I don't know is how to make a proper toggle to make them .`VISIBLE/.GONE` whenever a button is clicked.

Here is what I need:I have a `linear layout` with some `buttons` inside. I need them `buttons` hidden in the first place, so I set the `linear layout` as gone:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/feelings_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/feeling_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/happy_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:text="Happy"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sad_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:text="Sad"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/love_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:text="in love"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mad_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:text="mad"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I make'em .`VISIBLE` when a button is clicked and .`GONE` again when the same `button` is pressed:

```
Button feelingsButton = (Button)contentView.findViewById(R.id.feeling_btn);
    feelingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            feelingsButtonsLayout = (LinearLayout)contentView.findViewById(R.id.feelings_layout);
            if(feelingsButtonsLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                Log.d("-----------", "gone");
                feelingsButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                Log.d("-----------", "not gone");
                for ( int i = 0; i < feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildCount();  i++ ){
                    View view = feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                feelingsButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything seems to work fine, but when I click the same button a third time, expecting it to make the layout `VISIBLE`, it won't show up again even though my `log`says the view is `gone` (looking at Logcat only, it seems to be working fine).

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the visibility of all your buttons again which were set to `GONE` at second click because

1st click => set you layout visible and all button are already visible

2nd click => set layout gone as well as all buttons

3rd click => set layout visible but buttons are still not visible which were set to gone while 2nd click

```
  if(feelingsButtonsLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                Log.d("-----------", "gone");
                for ( int i = 0; i < feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildCount();  i++ ){
                    View view = feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                feelingsButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                Log.d("-----------", "not gone");
                for ( int i = 0; i < feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildCount();  i++ ){
                    View view = feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildAt(i);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                feelingsButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

or

you can remove both the loops  and simply set your `container` layout visibility

```
  if(feelingsButtonsLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                Log.d("-----------", "gone");
                feelingsButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }else{
                Log.d("-----------", "not gone");
                feelingsButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```

Comment: thanks man, that's a great explanation. I just removed the loop and it all worked just fine. I'll mark the answer above as the accepted one though because it also solved my problem and he answered first ok? cheers!

Comment: @rob check the time who answered it first though explanation and answering both takes time , anyway i am glad that i could help

Comment: @rob you can give an upvote to helpful answer like of arun to appreciate his efforts too , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting `GONE` to all individual buttons, but setting `VISIBLE` on layout alone and not on buttons.

There is no need for hiding all buttons when parent layout is set to `GONE`. You can remove the below code from your `else` case

```
for ( int i = 0; i < feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildCount();  i++ ){
                View view = feelingsButtonsLayout.getChildAt(i);
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
```